# How to sign an apk file when I click "Run(Shift+F10)" on android studio?

Tags: android

I do follow some other guide. It get the right signature when I follow "**Build->generate signed APK**". But when I click "Run", it automatically use an unknown source signature. (Is the "run" called "debug mode"?) How can I sync them?

All I have done, it to get the **apk** SHA1 value.

I found another way:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to have a debug signing config for the app?

In your gradle you can specify a 'debug' signing config and a 'release' one.

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("debug.keystore")
        }


        myConfig {
            storeFile file("other.keystore")
            storePassword "android"
            keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
            keyPassword "android"
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        foo {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.myConfig
        }
    }
}
```

Google Guide: [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Signing-Configurations)

EDIT: Typo correction

Comment: So this doesn't need to add such as "storePassword "?

Comment: You can configure it as you like. You can add a password or not. The above code just tells the build system that you have different requirements for different builds.

Comment: Is my solution rigrt? Frank Brenyah

Comment: Yep! The one you found is actually the way it is recommended in the latest version of gradle. It should not give you issues. 'minifyEnabled` gives me issues when it is set to `true` because of an error in the proguard file. Hopefully you dont get that.